# Unable to Load Json File

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file that is as follows:

```
{
  "im_width" : 256,
  "im_height" : 256,
  "compressFolder" : "images",
  "TestFolder" : "TestImages",
  "TrainFolder" : "TrainImages",
  "compressFile" : "images.zip",
  "Epochs" : 70,
  "Batch" : 4,
  "Dropout" : 0.2,
  "Model_Path" : "./Best.h5",
  "LabelFiles" : "train_labels.csv"
}
```

I am trying to load this file from the following code:

```
import json

# Loading Config File
with open('./config.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
 File "Test.py", line 11, in <module>
    config = json.load(config_file)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/Train/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/Train/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/Train/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/test/anaconda3/envs/Train/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 13 column 1 (char 289)
```

Can someone please explain what is wrong with my code or Json file.

Comment: Check file encoding, content is legit and shouldn't cause any errors.

Comment: It is working in my system. Make sure the data you mentioned here and data in your file are same.

Comment: Can confirm, works for me as well.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, You have to take a look closely at "line 13 column 1".

char289 might be there. It means that you have to make sure JSON file's encoding is correct. 289 value is not in the range of ASCII.

Also, you can try this

```
with open('./config.json', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
```